# Error in showing URL data in php

Tags: php, url, data-transfer

I am trying to capture a value form requested URL in php. My code is given below:

```
http_get("http://domain.com/view.php?token=", $value); 
 echo $value;
```

But once I go to this `url http://domain.com/view.php?token=myvalue"`  I am getting the following error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_get() in F:\Server\xampp\htdocs\p\data-repository\view.php on line 11
```

My primary objective is to show the `$value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get value from the URL,you can use either of GET or REQUEST method in PHP.

Using GET

```
$value=$_GET['token'];
echo $value;
```

Using REQUEST

```
$value=$_REQUEST['token'];
echo $value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like:

```
$value = $_GET['token'];
echo $value;
```

OR - try assigning http_get to a variable (as shown in the manual):

```
$response = http_get("http://www.example.com/", array("timeout"=>1), $info);
print_r($info);
```

Comment: actually, I want to get the value of  specific parameter from the URL. Suppose you write www.domain.com/view.php?token=Ryan in your browser, you should see the "Ryan" as the output in your browser

Comment: Not sure, why the code form manual returns with the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

http_get is function to receive of http request.
If you want GET value, use this:

```
$_GET['token']
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the apache log? Are you sure pecl_http is installed and enabled?

Also be aware [http_get](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-get.php) returns a string (the result of the website). The second argument is supposed to be the options. The third argument will be filled with the server response.

You could also try to use [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) ([curl_init()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php), [curl_setopt()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), [curl_exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php), [curl_close()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-close.php)).

Comment: good eye, Horse SMith - there are several possible prerequisites, depending on your OS: http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.requirements.php